# Player moves correct speed across the screen, walk cycle is too fast, hoping for suggestions to do it properly

Tags: python, animation, pygame, game-engine

I'm jumping around tutorials trying to successfully complete my first game. I was taking a heavy object oriented approach for managing resources, but I felt that was clouding my understanding a bit, so I restarted. I currently have my character moving smoothly across the screen at a speed I like, my problem is my "walk cycle" of three images goes way to fast, and I get a persistence of vision effect on my little chicken's legs. I need to slow it down, so far I was able to achieve a desired effect by popping in a call to the clock after each decision loop, but I am worried that will slow down the entire game logic, as I am not sure if calling clock more than once is "freezing" my game update in time while the character decides to move. I had considered maybe making some type of equation comparing the time on the clock to the time on the clock before, to slow down the walk cycle key frames. Any help or suggestions, is there an easier method? Thanks a bunch.
    import pygame, sys
    from pygame.locals import *

```
pygame.init()

#Contstants
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
SCREENWIDTH = 300
SCREENHEIGHT = 300
game_running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#variables
current = 0
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.avatar_front = pygame.image.load("chicken_front.png")
        self.avatar_back = pygame.image.load("chicken_back.png")
        self.avatar_right = pygame.image.load("chicken_right_stand.png")
        self.avatar_left = pygame.image.load("chicken_left_stand.png")
        self.avatar_left_walk = pygame.image.load("chicken_left_walk1.png")
        self.avatar_left_walk2 = pygame.image.load("chicken_left_walk2.png")     
        self.avatar_right = pygame.image.load("chicken_right_stand.png")
        self.avatar_right_walk = pygame.image.load("chicken_right_walk1.png")
        self.avatar_right_walk2 = pygame.image.load("chicken_right_walk2.png")
        self.position = [0, 0]
        self.current_direction = self.avatar_front

#SetUp
myScreen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Chicken Rush!")
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("chicken_front.png"))
myPlayer = Player()

while game_running:

    myScreen.fill(BLACK)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    #RIGHT HERE DETERMINES WHICH IMAGE TO DISPLAY FOR WALKING LEFT->This is the part I need to     #       slow down       
    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()       
    if keys_pressed[K_LEFT] and myPlayer.position[0] >= 0:
        if current == 0:
            myPlayer.current_direction = myPlayer.avatar_left
            current += 1
        elif current == 1:
            myPlayer.current_direction = myPlayer.avatar_left_walk
            current += 1
        elif current == 2:
            myPlayer.current_direction = myPlayer.avatar_left_walk2
            current = 0
        myPlayer.position[0] -= 3
    if keys_pressed[K_RIGHT] and myPlayer.position[0] < SCREENWIDTH - 32:
        myPlayer.position[0] += 3
    if keys_pressed[K_UP] and myPlayer.position[1] >= 0:
        myPlayer.position[1] -= 3
    if keys_pressed[K_DOWN] and myPlayer.position[1] < SCREENHEIGHT - 35:
        myPlayer.position[1] += 3

    myScreen.blit(myPlayer.current_direction, (myPlayer.position[0], myPlayer.position[1]))

    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(28)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you could use a longer interval to slow down the image transitions. Keep in mind you'll need to play with the value of `imageTransitionSpeed` to get it to your liking, but something like this should help slow the transition down:

```
#RIGHT HERE DETERMINES WHICH IMAGE TO DISPLAY FOR WALKING LEFT->This is the part I need to     #       slow down       
    imageTransitionSpeed = 10
    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()       
    if keys_pressed[K_LEFT] and myPlayer.position[0] >= 0:
        if current == 0:
            myPlayer.current_direction = myPlayer.avatar_left
            current += 1
        elif current == imageTransitionSpeed:
            myPlayer.current_direction = myPlayer.avatar_left_walk
            current += 1
        elif current == (imageTransitionSpeed * 2):
            myPlayer.current_direction = myPlayer.avatar_left_walk2
            current = 0
        else:
            current += 1
        myPlayer.position[0] -= 3
    if keys_pressed[K_RIGHT] and myPlayer.position[0] < SCREENWIDTH - 32:
        myPlayer.position[0] += 3
    if keys_pressed[K_UP] and myPlayer.position[1] >= 0:
        myPlayer.position[1] -= 3
    if keys_pressed[K_DOWN] and myPlayer.position[1] < SCREENHEIGHT - 35:
        myPlayer.position[1] += 3

    myScreen.blit(myPlayer.current_direction, (myPlayer.position[0], myPlayer.position[1]))

    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(28)
```

Comment: That appeared to give me the same results as when I just modified elif current == 0, current == 10, and current == 20, it ends up locking on the avatar_left image if I do anything but current == 0, current == 1, current == 2, sounds like we were thinking along the same lines, just have to figure what's breaking it once implementing it. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Did you add the "`else: current += 1`" statement?

Comment: Nope, I caught that right before you posted it, and it fixed and does exactly what I wanted to do now. Thanks for helping me. I can only assume it was getting stuck because it didn't know what to do in the values between my "set frames" since I went with elseif, but we got it working. Thanks again.